# Is it possible to access the properties of an external program in .NET?

Tags: c#, .net

I'm not sure if this is possible. But if I have an .exe file stored somewhere I can access it (e.g. my desktop) which has a version number variable stored in the details tab of the file's properties **(not talking about the programming construct of gettable/settable properties here).** Can I access this property in .NET?

All examples I've seen seem to reference the local program properties.

If the above is not possible, is there any way to make certain information about a program available for other programs to access and read?

**EDIT: I don't just want version info, I'll also need to access date modified and file size and possibly other properties in the details tab later on**

Comment: @Ani I'm actually not specifically requesting Version info, but instead access to all properties that appear in the details tab. Version info is just one example of what I will need to access.

Comment: You can try exploring File, FileInfo and FileVersionInfo classes to get the required details.

Comment: @AshishCharan This is the correct answer. The one I have been looking for. Please feel free to put this below and I will accept it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try exploring File, FileInfo and FileVersionInfo classes to get the required details.

Comment: Yes, this is what I was looking for. I find it a bit odd that the file version info appears to be in its own class and not as a property in FileInfo, but no doubt there good reason for this (although it's not always easy to spot that reason)

Comment: @Chibbles: Version info is a separate class because it makes sense for only certain types of files.

Comment: @Giorgi That makes a lot more sense now. I hadn't considered differing file types and the associated information they might or might not need.

Answer (score 6):

You can use [FileVersionInfo](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.fileversioninfo%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) class to get the version of another program.

```
FileVersionInfo myFileVersionInfo = FileVersionInfo.GetVersionInfo(Environment.SystemDirectory + "\\Notepad.exe");

Console.WriteLine("File: " + myFileVersionInfo.FileDescription + '\n' +
                  "Version number: " + myFileVersionInfo.FileVersion);
```

Answer (score 2):

If I'm not wrong, you are trying to fetch the version number of a file using c#. You can try the below example:

```
using System;
using System.IO;
using System.Diagnostics;

class Class1
{
     public static void Main(string[] args)
     {
    // Get the file version for the notepad. 
    // Use either of the two following commands.
    FileVersionInfo.GetVersionInfo(Path.Combine(Environment.SystemDirectory, "Notepad.exe"));
    FileVersionInfo myFileVersionInfo = FileVersionInfo.GetVersionInfo(Environment.SystemDirectory + "\\Notepad.exe");


    // Print the file name and version number.
    Console.WriteLine("File: " + myFileVersionInfo.FileDescription + '\n' +
       "Version number: " + myFileVersionInfo.FileVersion);
    }

}
```

Source: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.fileversioninfo(v=vs.110).aspx